# Does a custom classloader makes the code invisible for a client?

Tags: java, classloader

I want a java applet in a html page but the source code can't be visible is this possible with a custom classloader?

Comment: How exactly is your code supposed to run on the client side if it isn't stored somewhere on the client, and hence available to whoever controls the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom ClassLoader that decodes classes from random bytes. However, this ClassLoader itself is a class and needs to be loaded in a default way for JVM to understand it. And the user can decompile it, effectively getting to know how to decode your other classes.

What is done in practice is to use obfuscator. We use Proguard at our company.

Comment: thanx aloth! Is a jar file or applet or something ever decompiled or is proguard almost 100% safe?

Comment: It can be decompiled, but it's obfuscated into rubbish - so to understand the code or to modify it is quite hard.